# Trouble converting multi-module gradle script to kotlin dsl

Tags: android, kotlin, gradle

Consider a simple multi module Android project setup similar to:

```
app
common
```

Where the `app` module and `common` module both need to implement some shared gradle logic, i.e.:

```
android {
    testOptions {
        unitTests {
            returnDefaultValues = true
        }
        animationsDisabled = true
    }

    lint {
        abortOnError = false
    }
}
```

When I use the groovy dsl to specify the above logic, and then use `apply from: rootProject.file('common.gradle')` the project works fine.  But when I use the kotlin dsl to contain specify the above logic, I get the following errors:

```
Unresolved reference: android
Unresolved reference: testOptions
Unresolved reference: unitTests
...
```

The groovy vs kotlin dsl version are *exactly* the same, mind you.  Just changing the file extension to have `.kts` breaks the build.

Am I doing something wrong here? Or is this a known issue/limitation?

Answer (score 0):

Since Kotlin DSL requires compilation you cant use `android {}` block in kts files like you did using Groovy because AGP is not available for kts files except `build.gradle.kts`

The only options to separete some logic from build.gradle.kts are [convention plugin](https://docs.gradle.org/current/samples/sample_convention_plugins.html) or regular gradle plugin